# How to make OneNote for Windows 10 / Android auto sync more frequently

Tags: windows-10, android, sync, microsoft-onenote

I'm using One Note in 2 devices:

- **OneNote for Windows 10** Version 16001.14326 on Windows 11 PC
- **Microsoft OneNote for Android** on a Samsung Galaxy S9 Version 16.0.15726 (updated Nov 8, 2022)

In the Windows app I turn on the "Sync notebooks automatically" option, and in the Android app I turn on the "Sync all page content" already.

However, I **sometimes** notice (about 10% of the time) that even though both devices are connected to my local LAN, there is a lag for one device to detect a change made in the other device, **even if the update happened a few hours before**.  The tell-tale sign is that the latest updated page is *not* at the time in the "Recent Notes" section.

For example, today I made a change to one page using the Android app at 8am but when I open the same page in the Windows app at 11am, the change does not appear in the page although I made sure that "Page Sync status" icon on the top bar *already* displays "Page last synced just now".  I stare at the page for more than 3 minutes (not wanting to add anything yet to avoid creating a conflict version) and suddenly the update appears without my doing anything.

**My question**: How do I force OneNote for Windows to sync when automatic sync seems to intermittently lag behind?

Comment: Which Windows app are you using? The Onenote app from the Microsoft Store is said to sync faster than the desktop version. The web client is also much faster on sync.

Comment: @harrymc I'm using the Microsoft Store version already, the Windows App, not the full featured Office 365 version.